# Summarize data in a new table

Tags: mysql

The problem is as follows during the day data is put into status_table (this can reach up to 4000 entries a day

During the night i want to put the data in a more organized way in a storage table
(status_table_storage) and remove it from the  status_table.
The idea is to group all the entries that have the same status until the status/error changes. from that point on a new group should start an be placed into the table. an example can be found in the fiddle

what is the best way to do this.

an example of the table structure can be found here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/488524/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step by step explanation:

First you order the table by name and timestamp and initialize three [user-defined variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html).

```
SELECT s.* FROM status_table s
, (SELECT @group_number := 0, @prevName := NULL, @prevStatus := NULL) var_init_subquery
ORDER BY name, timestamp
```

As you can see, we can use a subquery for that. The `ORDER BY` is important, because there's no order in a relational database, unless you specify it.

Now, MySQL evaluates the `SELECT` clause in the specified order, therefore don't change the order here.

```
SELECT 
s.*,
@prevName,
@prevStatus,
@prevName := s.name,
@prevStatus := s.status
FROM status_table s
, (SELECT @group_number := 0, @prevName := NULL, @prevStatus := NULL) var_init_subquery
ORDER BY name, timestamp
```

When you execute this statement, you can see, that when we simply select the variables they hold the value of the previous row or NULL when it's the first row, that was read. Then the value of the current row is assigned to the variables. So we can compare now the current row with the previous row. If something changed, we simply increment the third variable, which is a number for each "group" that we are building.

```
SELECT 
s.*,
@group_number := IF(@prevName != s.name OR @prevStatus != s.status, @group_number + 1, @group_number) AS group_number,
@prevName := s.name,
@prevStatus := s.status
FROM status_table s
, (SELECT @group_number := 0, @prevName := NULL, @prevStatus := NULL) var_init_subquery
ORDER BY name, timestamp
```

So we incremented the `@group_number` when something changed and assigned the variable to itself if not, so that it doesn't change.

Now we can simply use this query as subquery and do a simple grouping.

```
SELECT 
group_number AS id, 
name, 
status, 
MIN(error) AS error, 
MIN(timestamp) AS firstEntry,
MAX(timestamp) AS lastEntry,
COUNT(*) AS entries
FROM (
    SELECT 
    s.*,
    @group_number := IF(@prevName != s.name OR @prevStatus != s.status, @group_number + 1, @group_number) AS group_number,
    @prevName := s.name,
    @prevStatus := s.status
    FROM status_table s
    , (SELECT @group_number := 0, @prevName := NULL, @prevStatus := NULL) var_init_subquery
    ORDER BY name, timestamp
) sq
GROUP BY 
group_number, 
name, 
status
```

- see it working in this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/488524/6/2)