# It is possible to merge rows chronologically?

Tags: mysql, sql, merge

I need to track user activity.

I have next table

```
select * from acct order by stopTime;

locationId  startTime stopTime
1           1         2
1           3         4
1           5         6
2           7         8
2           9         10
1           11        12
1           13        14
1           15        16
```

I need merge adjacent rows (and their time periods.) only if they have same `locationId`. It is not grouping by `locationId`.

```
     locationId  startTime stopTime
     1           1         6       -- merged rows 1-3
     2           7         10      -- merged rows 4-5
     1           11        16      -- merged rows 6-8
```

It is possible to make the result using Mysql query or I can aggregate this statistic using programming language only?

Comment: What if there are gaps between the `stopTime` and the `startTime`?

Comment: Use two user variables, one to track location the other to track a rank.  when the locationID changes increment the rank.  this becomes a subquery which contains a different rank for each change in locationID, then you can simply group by the rank and get min/max from start/stop time and max of locationId.

Comment: The common name of this problem is "gaps and islands".

Comment: A code example with step by step explanation of what xQbert said, can be found in my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43866348/summarize-data-in-a-new-table/43867080#43867080 You just have to adjust the column names :)

Comment: http://rextester.com/EFXIL80101 completed example using table/columns above.

Comment: @xQbert thank you for answer. This is what I was looking for. You can post the solution as an answer if you want.

Comment: I can not; closed as duplicate means I'm unable to post an answer.